# SQL Server 2008 - conversion from string to int fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, casting

Don't know why this conversion fails.

```
SELECT CAST('32.999' AS INT)
```

throws the error saying

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '32.000' to data
>   type int.

I know I can convert it to `Decimal` and then convert it to `Int` but why 32.000 is not being converted to `Int` directly?

Am I missing something here?

--EDIT--

I don't care about the decimal points. I want SQL to ignore them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

32.000 can not be represented accurately as an int due to the decimal places. Instead, if you want a numeric value with decimals, you can use a float (or numeric) data type.

```
Select CAST('32.000' as float)
```

edit: misread your question a little bit.

I'm assuming SQL is trying it's best to preserve your intentions. When it reads in that the numeric value you're attempting to cast has decimal values, it will flat out reject it.

Comment: good point but i dont care abt the decimal points. i want SQL to ignore them.

Comment: If you cast '32.000' to a float, the display of that value will be '32'. It won't attempt to display decimal values that are .000

Comment: @Asdfg SQL won't let you ignore them unless you explicitly tell it to do so. One way to do that is to `CAST` as suggested. Another way is to not include them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

used `SELECT CAST(ROUND('32.999',0,1) AS INT)` and it works well.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you have a value of '32.9' that you attempt to round, it will result in 33.

However, Round('32.000', 0, 1) will result correctly in 32.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx